# How to establish a boost asio tcp socket over http proxy?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio, http-proxy

I am trying to establish a TCP socket over http proxy. My current understand is,

1. create tcp socket connecting to http_proxy_ip:http_proxy_port
2. Via the socket send: CONNECT http://my.server.com:80 HTTP/1.0\r\n\r\n

My question is : is there need to wrap each tcp packet with some http header or use it like normal TCP sokcet(which is not over http proxy)?

Is there any equivalent for boost::asio [TCP connection through http proxy](http://www.example-code.com/vcpp/socket_http_proxy.asp)

Thanks.